# Matrices: $AB=0 \implies A=0 \text{ or } \ B=0$

Tags: matrices

When A and B are square matrices of the same order, and O is the zero square matrix of the same order, prove or disprove:-
$$AB=0 \implies A=0 \text{ or } \ B=0$$

I proved it as follows:-

Assume $A \neq O$ and $ B \neq O$:
 then, $$ |A||B| \neq 0 $$
$$ |AB| \neq 0 $$
$$ AB \neq O $$
$$ \therefore A \neq O\ and\ B \neq O \implies AB \neq O $$
$$ \neg[ AB \neq O] \implies \neg [ A \neq O\ and\ B \neq O ] $$
$$AB=O \implies A=O \text{ or } \ B=O$$

But when considering, 
A := \begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\1&1
\end{pmatrix} and B:= \begin{pmatrix} -1& 1\\ 1 &-1
\end{pmatrix}then, AB=O and A$\neq $O and B $\neq$ O

I can't figure out which one and where I went wrong.

Comment: You went wrong when you wrote "Then $|A||B|\neq0$".

Comment: How do you define $|A|$?

Comment: Why are you using $O$ and $0$ differently? What do these mean to you?

Comment: If $|A|$ is the dterminant, then it is not true that $A\neq O\implies |A|\neq 0$.

Comment: Git Gud has already pointed out your mistake. Check the case of your own example, both $A$ and $B$ have determinant $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saying that if $A \neq O$ then, $det(A) \neq O$, which is false in general. Consider any diagonal matrix different from $O$ which has at least one zero in the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first approach is that there exist non-zero matrices with zero determinant. For instance, $A$ and $B$ in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't wrong! AB = O does not imply that either A or B is zero. In matrices there is no such case. So even when A is not equal to O and B is not equal to zero, you can get AB =O. Voila!

Comment: This old question already has an accepted answer. What's the point of your answer?